# Three.js - change face size on planeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to change faces coordinates by modify the vertices.
The values of the variables are correct, but no change on the screen.

This is the [plain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKGFg.png)

And this is my code :

```
    var geometry = editor.selected.geometry;
    var vertices = geometry.vertices;

    vertices[1] = new THREE.Vector3(-100 / 3, 50, 0);
    vertices[5] = new THREE.Vector3(-100 / 3, 0, 0);

    var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];

    uvs[0] = [new THREE.Vector2(0, 1), new THREE.Vector2(0, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(1 / 6, 1)];
    uvs[1] = [new THREE.Vector2(0, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(1 / 6, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(1 / 6, 1)];
    uvs[2] = [new THREE.Vector2(1 / 6, 1), new THREE.Vector2(1 / 6, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(2 / 3, 1)];
    uvs[3] = [new THREE.Vector2(1/ 6, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(2 / 3, 0.5), new THREE.Vector2(2 / 3, 1)];

    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();

    geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
    geometry.__dirtyNormals = true;

    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing vertices that lie inside the border of the shape. Thats why you dont see a change. If you turn on `wireframe` on your material you will see that the vertices do change. Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6pzvjxj/

Also for your `uvs` it should be:

```
var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
```

Comment: yes, thanks, this vertices/geometry mistake is only here, not in the code.

and i'm aware of what you said about the in-border vertices, the thing is  - i have there a meshFaceMaterial with two textures (see image added in original question), and still i cant see the difference...